# Swagger Configuration to Specify Authentication Schema

Tags: java, swagger

I have specified the Swagger annotations, used to generate the Security/Authentication required for the API; as per the Swagger documentation.

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "Add a new pet to the store", 
    authorizations = {
          @Authorization(
                  value="petoauth", 
                  scopes = {
                          @AuthorizationScope(
                                  scope = "add:pet", 
                                  description = "allows adding of pets")
                          }
                  )
    }
  )
```

After adding this code and generating documentation, as part of documentation I see "Type" for Security section set to "Unknown".
Can I control the same and set it to any custom value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over researching a bit further found that while specifying the swagger-maven-plugin and configuring it under pom (pom.xml of your module) specify this configuration there:

```
<securityDefinition>
    <name>basicAuth</name>
    <type>basic</type>
</securityDefinition>
```

(One of the Stackoverflow answers points to this without much details, but missed the link for the same. If someone finds it, please link it over here to give due credit)

Also, important to note here is the type value. These need to be either of :
- basic 
- oauth2 
(Someone can correct me on this point, but as per my observation found this)